# Creating a feature class in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis

I am trying to create a feature class from another feature class via below:

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, name, "POLYGON")
```

In ArcGIS, it is creating the fields `Shape`, `Shape_Length`, and `Shape_Area`. I added additional fields to the newly feature class.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("old featureclass", ["Shape@", "*"]
insert = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("new featureclass", ["*"]
for i in cursor:
    insert.insertRow(i)
```

I am getting an error:

> Sequence size must match size of the row

This is because the newly feature class has added additional fields as I mentioned above.  Then I tried

```
for i in cursor:
    append newly array with (ShapeLength, and ShapeArea)
    insert.insertRow(newlyarray)
```

It worked fine but the `Shape_Area` and `Shape_Length` is returning zero.  I've also tried to calculate field area and it didn't work as well.

Can someone please help me with this issue? The geometry shape is a polygon but the shape area and shape length won't populate based of the pre-existing shape.

Comment: Are you aware there is a [GIS.SE] Stack Exchange?  It may be worth asking this question there.

Comment: When you say "trying to create a feature class from another feature class" -- are you trying to copy the data from one to another? Are you simply interested in duplicating the schema, or also the features? // Generally: *can you please post your complete code?* (The snippets you have here will not execute, and I am having trouble understanding your goal.)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

Get the fields list from the old shapefile, 
Add the desired fields to the new file, 
then iterate over each field (or just the ones you want to copy) of each row from the old file and copy the value into its corresponding field in the new file. 
Then you can add your brand new new fields whenever you like and this copying function won't be affected if it refers to fields by name.

Another method would be to literally copy the old shapefile using the copy tool, then edit the copied file.